# Selenium chrome cached data issue with whatsapp web

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, whatsapp

I encountered an issue with chrome when using selenium with python.
When the script runs the first time it works but after It won't.
The cached data have some issues, When I try to delete the cache in settings, it shows "**Cached images and files
Calculating …**" and keeps loading forever.
Also some websites don't work like WhatsApp web.
I discovered a workaround,
is to delete the cache directory under the Default directory and reopen chrome.

So I set my script to delete this directory before launching chrome, but I encounter a lot of errors (Permission denied, etc..), Or using the `--disable-application-cache=0` option .
But this workarounds aren't best practices.

Is there any fix to this issue? (I'm sure the problem isn't in my selenium script because the bug stills even if I launch chrome by myself).

Here's my code:

```
def __init__(self, wait, session=None,headless=False,logging_in=False):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en-US")
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.41 Safari/537.36")
    if session:
        
        chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir={}".format(os.path.abspath(session)))
        chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
        if headless and os.path.exists(os.path.abspath(session)) and not os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"not_logged.in")):
            chrome_options.add_argument("headless")
            
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)  # we are using chrome as our webbrowser
    else:
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    self.browser.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
```

I can add this to solve the issue:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-application-cache=0")
```

This disables caching which I don't want to do especially for WhatsApp.

Comment: Update the question with your complete code trials.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is multiple instances of chromedriver.exe using the same user directory, wich causes the cache loading issue, so you need to ensure that you quit from every session you start (Even if the script fails) using:

```
driver.quit()
```